# Object defined outside fetch but not inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

I'm using tmi.js to get the data of a chat message on www.twitch.tv.

This is my code:

```
const tmi = require('tmi.js');
require('dotenv').config();

const options = {
  options: {
    debug: true
  },
  identity: {
    username: process.env.OAUTH_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.OAUTH_PASSWORD
  },
  connection: {
    reconnect: true
  },
  channels: [`instak`]
};

const client = new tmi.client(options);

client.on(`chat`, (channel, userstate, message/*, self */) => {
  console.log(userstate.username); //This logs my userstate, I can see the username which is passed on correctly.
  switch (message) {
    case `!kluiten`:
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/users/${userstate.username}`) // fetch from Express.js server
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(`USERSTATE IS`, userstate);
        client.action(channel, `${userstate[`display-name`]}, you've got ${result.instakluiten} instakluiten.`);
      });
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

// Connect the client to the server..
client.connect();
```

As I said in the commented part after the console.log(userstate), I get all the correct information I was expecting, so outside of the switch case and the fetch. However, when I log my userstate.username inside the fetch, userstate is undefined... I don't see why that happens, because when I did it in the front-end I had no problems... Now I'm doing it in node and it's undefined...

This looks like a common "you need to wait for your response"-problem, but I don't see a logical explanation for that being the problem because in the client.on(`chat`) userstate is defined... I'm troubled.

Comment: The TMI client is probably mutating `userstate` after the handler finishes.

Comment: Am I not still using the `userstate` inside the handler? So inside of it I should still be able to use it... No? If not, is there any path you can put me on to search for a solution?

Comment: No; the handler has finished, and your code is running later.

Comment: But why was I able to do it on the front-end then though?